# A question on decidability

Tags: computability, undecidability, decision-problem, rice-theorem

I have a homework question that is as follows:

*L(P) is a language of ASCII input strings for which a given program, P, returns "yes". Is the set of all input strings P decidable, such that P is a decision program and L(P) is decidable?*

My intuition leads me to believe that the set is, in fact, decidable but I am having a tough time proving my answer.

Would appreciate any help on this. Thanks

Comment: Im struggling to understand the language you want to show decidability for. Can you formally define it (with mathematical symbols)?

Comment: Is it the set of all turing machine repersentations with decidable languages?

Comment: The language is the set of strings P where P is a python decision program, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L=\{\langle M \rangle \mid M \text{ is a TM such }L(M)\in R\}$, where $\langle M\rangle$ is the encoding of a TM $M$, and $R$ is the set of all decidable languages. This is the language in question.

Notice that $R\neq \emptyset$ and also since there are languages not in $R$ (like the halting problem), then $R\neq RE$. Simply put, $R$ is *not* trivial (obviously).

Apply Rice's theorem on the property $"R"$, to directly get that $L$ is not decidable.

Comment: Note that Rice's theorem only provides a *lower* complexity bound. In fact $L$ is substantially more complicated than that: it's $\Sigma^0_3$-complete, so Turing-equivalent to [${\bf 0'''}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump) (basically "the halting problem's halting problem's halting problem"). Proving this takes work though.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this clearly. I think it was the layout of the question that I was struggling to understand.

Comment: Seems like it. Next time, try to write down the formal definition of the language and work with it. It makes everything much simpler to think of!